# Copying char by char from RichEdit to PDF sets wrong character spacing

Tags: delphi, pdf, rtf, delphi-xe5

I'm working on an app for sending bills. The client must have the ability to add a leter in rich format. Using Debenu, I scan and then print char by char to retrieve the font styles. This works pretty good, accept for the printing.

The Picture to the left is my richedit and to the right is my PDF. As you can see, character spacing is a little bid off

[image]
[image: PDF Text]

This is a small bit of code that does the copying and character spacing.

'XPos' is the left position of the line. After each printed char, I'm adding the width of the selected char to XPos

```
XPos := 42;
for I := 0 to length(RichEdit.Text) - 1 do
begin
  RichEdit.SelStart := I;
  RichEdit.SelLength := 1;
  PDF.DrawText(XPos, YPos, RichEdit.SelText);
  XPos := XPos + Canvas.TextWidth(RichEdit.SelText);
end;
```

The X and YPos for the PDF are floats, while the Canvas.TextWidth are in integers. Is it possible the actual positions on the canvas are a bit more accurate? If that is the case, how do I get those positions in floats?

I'm using Delphi XE-5 and Debenu Quick PDF Library 9.1 for creating the pdf's.

Edit:

As pointed out by LU RD. In FireMonkey the Canvas.Textwidth are floats. I did a quick check with an EditBox, Button and Label:

```
Label1.Text := floattostr(Canvas.TextWidth(edit1.seltext));
```

In this test the Label shows a very specific number for char width.

[image]

This leaves me to believe that I was right that char width's are indeed floats and I need to start implementing mjn's sugestion of transferring a full string with the same properties to my PDF.

Comment: Using FireMonkey, the [FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.TextWidth](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.TextWidth) is a float. But no FMX.TRichEdit unfortunately.

Comment: For all characters which use the same text properties, the code could transfer everything in one operation, instead of copying char-by-char.

Comment: You can write directly the rich edit to the PDF as stated by http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=315#p315

Comment: @mjn That is my backup plan. For now i'd like to know why the system I have now doesn't work

Comment: @arnaudbouchez Thank you. I'm gonna look into TGDIPages as an aternative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debenu has this function:

```
function TDebenuPDFLibrary0915.CharWidth(CharCode: Integer): Integer;
```

If you devide the return value by 1000 and multiply it by the text size, you will get the right width for the char.
This is the solution to my own question:

```
XPos := 42;
for I := 0 to length(RichEdit.Text) do
begin
  RichEdit.SelStart := I;
  RichEdit.SelLength := 1;   
  PDF.DrawText(XPos, YPos, RichEdit.SelText);

  str := RichEdit.SelText;
  if length(str) > 0 then
    chr := char(str[1]);
  XPos := XPos + (PDF.CharWidth(Ord(chr)) / 1000 * 12);
end;
```

Mind you, this is still work in progress. But the essential is here.